# How to index related tables in solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to index my database for a question answer website. To start off, I want to index the `questions` and `answers` table which has a one to many relationship. I would expect solr to return documents like:

```
{   
  'question_id': 1,
  'question': 'Is this a question?',
  'answers' : [
    {
      'answer_id': 1,
      'answer': 'Maybe'
    },
    {
      'answer_id': 2,
      'answer': 'yes it is'
    }
  ]
}
```

What configuration do I need to achieve this?
I've gone through [Configuring the DIH Configuration File](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html) tutorial.

Below are the configurations I've tried:
CONFIG 1

```
<dataConfig>

  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/questionsdb" user="root" password=""/>
  <document>   
    <entity name="questions" 
            pk="id"
            query="SELECT id, title FROM questions">    
      <field column="id" name="question_id"/>
      <field column="title" name="title"/>

      <entity name="answers"
              pk="id"
              query="select id, answer from answers where qid='${questions.id}'"> 
        <field name="answer_id" column="id" />
        <field name="answer" column="answer" />
      </entity>
    </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

QUERY OUTPUT:
[image: Query Output]

CONFIG 2

```
<dataConfig>

  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/questionsdb" user="root" password=""/>
  <document>   
    <entity name="questions" 
            query="SELECT questions.id as question_id, questions.title as question, answers.id as answer_id, answers.answer as answer FROM questions JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.qid">    
      <field column="id" name="question_id"/>
      <field column="title" name="title"/>
      <field name="answer" column="answer" />
      <field name="answer_id" column="answer_id" />
    </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

QUERY OUTPUT:
[image]

I'm using solr 8.6.

EDIT 1:

Updated my `managed-schema` file to use `multiValued="true"`:

```
<field name="question" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="question_id" type="pint" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="answer" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="answer_id" type="pint" indexed="false" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

The output indexes the answers now but the `answer` and `answer_id` come up as a list.
Is it possible to restructure them to be returned as a list of dictionaries as given in the example structure above?

[image]

Comment: did you try something like `<field name="answers" column="answer" multiValued="true"/>` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing multi-valued field into Solr from mySQL using Solr Data Import Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20233837/importing-multi-valued-field-into-solr-from-mysql-using-solr-data-import-handler)

Comment: @uylmz Thanks! That did solve the initial issue. Is it possible to restructure the response as I want? Updated the question

Comment: using nested documents in solr is a whole other issue: https://medium.com/@alisazhila/solr-s-nesting-on-solr-s-capabilities-to-handle-deeply-nested-document-structures-50eeaaa4347a https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/indexing-nested-documents.html#:~:text=By%20way%20of%20example%2C%20nested,other%20variations%20as%20child%20documents choose the documentation version matching your solr